# How can I create Multiple Shipments in Magento via SOAP?

Tags: soap, magento

I'm using SOAP to add a shipment to a Magento order but I need to have the ability to modify existing shipments, and add additional shipments.

I can add a shipment and a track # but if the user voids a shipment for some reason I'd like to remove the shipment and then create a new shipment. I don't see a way to do this.

If I just try to add another shipment then I get a SOAP error.

Uncaught SoapFault exception: [102] Cannot do shipment for order

Comment: Were you able to add a new shipment to the same order or an order can only have one shipment ?

Answer (score -3):

yes you can do it,you need creat SOAP app for shipment & you need add new extension for magento.
example:
1.mine shipping app via SOAP,provide query shipping fee for magento.
http://ship.chinabuye.com/Soap_Server.php?wsdl
2.a plugin on magento side,can be defined SOAP URL & discount.you can preview in cart
http://www.chinabuye.com

Comment: what extension needs to be added? there is no way to do it with a default install?